# Averaging a data frame and adding a new column python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Country Year    Food Availability per capita (kg/cap/year)  Region
0   Afghanistan 1980    NaN Central and East Asia
1   Afghanistan 1981    NaN Central and East Asia
2   Afghanistan 1982    NaN Central and East Asia
3   Afghanistan 1983    NaN Central and East Asia
4   Afghanistan 1984    NaN Central and East Asia
... ... ... ... ...
2579    Zimbabwe    2009    141.317483  Southern Africa
2580    Zimbabwe    2010    136.990970  Southern Africa
2581    Zimbabwe    2011    139.933312  Southern Africa
2582    Zimbabwe    2012    142.318797  Southern Africa
2583    Zimbabwe    2013    143.292102  Southern Africa
```

Countries each have values of food availability for years from 1980 to 2013, and I would like to average them by region, that is, only have the average of food availability in each region every year. I tried to create a new dataframe for each region, then average the values, which worked, but I can't seem to add a new column to then initialize the region. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you provide the code which you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, might get you what you need:

```
df['yearly_avg_food_by_country_and_region'] = df.groupby(['year','country','region'])['food'].transform('mean')
```

It will create a column with the average food value per region and country per year.